# How can species pass on their genes to the next generation quantum mechanically at a distance?

Tags: physics, creature-design, reproduction

Suppose in one part of the universe unexplored by science, I imagine there exist a species that rely on quantum teleportation to transmit information about their genetic codes across to the other side of the universe. The mechanism still remain a mystery but in fact on Earth scientists had successfully proved the concept works and of course we would need an entangled pair of particles for this to work. I don't know much about quantum mechanics so how would the reproduction without copulation works?

Feel free to edit my post to make it more legible :)

Comment: As stated quantum entanglement doesn't allow passing information.  In addition quantum teleportation is a completely different concept and not related to entanglement.  It relies on the inexact nature of particles to allow them to decide to 'exist' somewhere else, because particles are really waves that sort of exist in many places at once.  However, this is random, you don't really get to control *where* the particle teleports to, and it's limited to very small distances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you could rely on entanglement to pass quantum information across the galaxy.  However, the rule that you cannot pass classical information faster than the speed of light applies.  Genetic information is classical information (you can measure its information content in bits), so it is impossible to transmit it faster than light using known physics.

You could elect to never "collapse" the quantum information it into classical information to get around this rule, but then it would not act very much like genetic material at all.  In fact, it would be impossible to use that information unless your entire creature remained in a quantum coherence for its entire life.  Such would be a very unique creature indeed (unique as in "you likely will get the physics wrong unless you have a PhD.  If you have a PhD, you'll probably still get it wrong unless you peer review your paper before publishing."  I am unaware at this time of any science fiction author attempting to get it right).

Comment: I see your point and I like to point out QM is incomplete and research is still on going. Experiment agrees with QM while Bell inequalities argue otherwise hence led to EPR paradox because either one of them is right or both are wrong. QM:"the moon is not there until I looked at it." also nature can produce excellence quantum computer such as plant (photosynthesis) and human are still having problem with coherence issue when only a few photons are involved.

Comment: Also important is that there are many interpretations of QM.  I believe "The moon is not there until I looked at it" is not true in the many-worlds interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

A very important thing to note here is that when an entangled pair snaps to one state or another, both parts of the pair do it simultaneously; however this can't be used to impart any information unless you have already passed on the information in a *classical* manner.

What this means for your race of distance breeders is that they'll either have already had some form of physical contact, or they're going to have to transmit the information via EM waves. At that point, you may as well forget the entangled pairs, because it's going to be considerably more effort for a race to set up and maintain pair entanglement (I'm not even sure how you'd do this without having some form of physical contact) that is then turned into usable genetic information by some classical interaction than it is to just rely on the classical interaction in the first place.

One possibility that maintains breeding at a distance but doesn't rely on entanglement is that the 'egg' of your species is sensitive to certain frequencies of the electromagnetic spectrum. The egg created by the mother contains half of the 'genetic' code (lets call it the Base) and a series of unpolarised (seems like a good enough word) chemicals that can then be pushed into various forms by the correct application of... ooh, lets go for Gamma radiation, because it sounds cool. Use neutrino if you want it to be nigh on undetectable, or visible light if you want it to look nice.

When a female goes into heat, they settle down and send out a pulse containing their Base information, encoded in a radiation pulse. A nearby male receives this pulse, and sends a pulse back encoding all of their genetic information, keyed to the mother's Base information. This then polarises (fertilises) the egg with that mother's specific Base, and forms babby. The two way mother/father communication will cut down on environmental fertilisation (which could be catastrophic).

TL:DR: There is no reason to use quantum entanglement, because you'll need something classical to transmit the information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

They don't.  You can have nonlocal corelation but *not* causality.  So I think you misunderstand what scientists have "really" found.

The best you can do is make use of quantum teleportation to *move* a state (not duplicate it) but only with regular communication too.

Why not learn something about quantum mechanics? You can ask stuff on [physics.se]

Comment: I'm referring to this recent [experiment](http://phys.org/news/2015-09-physicists-distance-quantum-teleportation.html)

Comment: That just reports a new distance record, not any new laws of physics. [Read up on quantum teleportation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) to find out about the general process involved, and grasp just what it can and can't do.

Comment: I think based on current physics it is forbidden for information to be created and travel faster than speed of light, in my case no information is created from nothing and it certainly obey the universal speed limit, I'm still reading the link you provided.

Comment: Transmitting information to "the other side of the universe" would take (assuming you mean the *observable* universe) 40 billion years. There's a limit to how far you could transmit before the expansion of the universe exceeds the signal's reach.

Answer (score 0):

Genes contain Genetic information. So, just like nay other information you can send it via Quantum Entanglement.

Now, lets say somebody did send the information across the universe. You still need some way to use this information, in this case, using it to create/build the next generation.

So, if we can assume that such a intelligent machine/being exists, i don't see why it can't be possible.